# duplicity: No signature chains found

Tags: google-drive-api, duplicity, duplicity-backup

Trying to use duplicity to list files in a backup that is in google drive. I get the error as in the title.

- I can see the folder and contents if I go to drive.google.com in the browser.
- I created a service account and downloaded the json file as defined [here](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#enable-api-access)
- The url I use is `gdrive://${GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_URL}/${FOLDER_NAME}?myDriveFolderID=root`
- GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_URL is the same as client_email in the json fle
- FOLDER_NAME is the textual name I see in the web browser
- The drive is for a company account and usually I access it by logging in normally, but with my work email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Need to share the drive with the service account
- Neet to not user FOLDER_NAME and instead use its ID in myDriveFolderID

Answer (score 0):

try the steps as outlined in the duplicity [man page section "A NOTE ON GDRIVE BACKEND"](https://duplicity.us/stable/duplicity.1.html#a-note-on-gdrive-backend) . they may not be outlined perfectly but reportedly work.

> Note Google has 2 drive methods, `Shared(previously Team) Drives` and
> `My Drive`, both can be shared but require different addressing
>
> For a Google Shared Drives folder
>
> Share Drive ID specified as a query parameter, driveID, in the backend
> URL. Example:
> gdrive://developer.gserviceaccount.com/target-folder/?driveID=
>
> For a Google My Drive based shared folder
>
> MyDrive folder ID specified as a query parameter, myDriveFolderID, in
> the backend URL Example export
> GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_URL=@.iam.gserviceaccount.com
> gdrive://${GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_URL}/?myDriveFolderID=root
>
> There are also two ways to authenticate to use GDrive: with a regular
> account or with a "service account". With a service account, a
> separate account is created, that is only accessible with Google APIs
> and not a web login. With a regular account, you can store backups in
> your normal Google Drive.
>
> To use a service account, go to the Google developers console at
> https://console.developers.google.com. Create a project, and make sure
> Drive API is enabled for the project. In the "Credentials" section,
> click "Create credentials", then select Service Account with JSON key.
>
> The GOOGLE_SERVICE_JSON_FILE environment variable needs to contain the
> path to the JSON file on duplicity invocation.
>
> export
> GOOGLE_SERVICE_JSON_FILE=<path-to-serviceaccount-credentials.json>
>
> The alternative is to use a regular account. To do this, start as
> above, but when creating a new Client ID, select "Create OAuth client
> ID", with application type of "Desktop app". Download the
> client_secret.json file for the new client, and set the
> GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET_JSON_FILE environment variable to the path to
> this file, and GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_FILE to a path to a file where
> duplicity will keep the authentication token - this location must be
> writable.
>
> NOTE: As a sanity check, GDrive checks the host and username from the
> URL against the JSON key, and refuses to proceed if the addresses do
> not match. Either the email (for the service accounts) or Client ID
> (for regular OAuth accounts) must be present in the URL. See URL
> FORMAT above.